# Normalizing Json file in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to normalize a Json file that looks like:

```
{
    "0": [
        [
            6,
            3.0
        ],
        [
            21,
            3.0
        ],
        [
            67,
            3.0
        ],
        [
            70,
            4.0
        ]
    ...
    "99": [
        [
            1,
            4.0
        ],
        [
            14,
            3.0
        ],
        [
            16,
            4.0
        ],
}
```

When I do `normalized_data = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)`, I get all the data in a single row but what I need is a unique entry for each tuple for example {0,6,3.0}, {0, 21, 3.0} and so on. Any leads on how to do this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `pd.read_json(data)`?

Comment: It gives me "ValueError: arrays must all be same length"

Comment: @HashimJaved you have different array `len` with items

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Right! So how would I go about reading that without getting an error?

Comment: @HashimJaved you need the same `len` in all items. you can do something like: `while (len(array) < max_array): array.append([None, None])`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar The array is the JSON file I'm trying to read and that file is read only so i can not append anything to it.

Comment: @HashimJaved just google how to read file and convert `json string` into `objects`.